# Transform Gauss Krüger Zone 3 data into WGS 84 / UTM 33N in QGIS

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, utm, germany

I would like to transform this data:
https://opendata.dwd.de/climate_environment/CDC/grids_germany/halfyear/precipitation/ (it is Gauss Krüger Zone 3) into WGS 84 / UTM 33N in QGIS.

How do I do it? Just setting to UTM didn't seem to work.

Comment: Try to reproject your data/layer from `EPSG:31467` into `EPSG:25832`. Check this [7.1. Lesson: Reprojecting and Transforming Data](https://docs.qgis.org/3.10/en/docs/training_manual/vector_analysis/reproject_transform.html#ls-reprojecting-and-transforming-data).

Comment: Setting is just telling QGIS "project the data using this CRS". Reprojecting is telling QGIS  "convert the coordinates of this data from CRS A to B".